# IIS 7.5 stops serving external requests randomly

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

Running IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2. 1-~10 times a week, usually over the weekend, our website will stop responding to external requests. I keep a browser window open on the server pointed to the internal IP. When this happens, I RDP into the server and refresh the browser on the server. The site immediately starts responding to external requests again. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to why this happens as I see nothing in the Event Viewer, the W3SV logs and no logs are being generated for failed request tracing. I also added ASP.net counters for Request Queued and Request Execution Time but it hasn't reported anything yet. CPU utilization looks normal when the site isn't responding.

Admittedly that's about the extent of my knowledge with this kind of stuff. Can anyone recommend anything else I can try? This is a WordPress site if that matters

Comment: Does the application pool stop? It will often shutdown after idle and the startup process may take some time.

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it. The site is unresponsive as I type this and the application pool in IIS says it is started and has 1 running application

Comment: There isn't enough information to diagnose so hopefully this will help: http://mvolo.com/troubleshoot-iis-hanging-requests/